# Datatables XSLX and CSV issue with export on Date Fields

Tags: javascript, datatables

I seem to be having a strange issue with Datatables and exporting to CSV and XSLX.

The export functionality in my code is fine, I get the files I need, but when I open the CSV or XSLX file in Excel the date fields are initially set to values consisting of `XXXXXXXX`

[image]

When I click the malformed date fields it renders as the correct date, but on initial opening of the file it does appear that there is a bug as you can see from the image above.

Note that when I open a regular CSV in a text editor that this is not an issue and the fields are rendered correctly.

How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
        // Must have thead and tbody in table
    $('#example').DataTable({
          dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    });
} );
</script>


<table id="example" style="width:100%">
    <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Position</th><th>Office</th><th>Age</th><th>Start date</th><th>Salary</th></tr></thead>

    <tbody><tr><td>Tiger Nixon</td><td>System Architect</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>61</td><td>2011/04/25</td><td>$320,800</td></tr><tr><td>Garrett Winters</td><td>Accountant</td><td>Tokyo</td><td>63</td><td>2011/07/25</td><td>$170,750</td></tr><tr><td>Ashton Cox</td><td>Junior Technical Author</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>66</td><td>2009/01/12</td><td>$86,000</td></tr><tr><td>Cedric Kelly</td><td>Senior Javascript Developer</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>22</td><td>2012/03/29</td><td>$433,060</td></tr><tr><td>Airi Satou</td><td>Accountant</td><td>Tokyo</td><td>33</td><td>2008/11/28</td><td>$162,700</td></tr><tr><td>Brielle Williamson</td><td>Integration Specialist</td><td>New York</td><td>61</td><td>2012/12/02</td><td>$372,000</td></tr><tr><td>Herrod Chandler</td><td>Sales Assistant</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>59</td><td>2012/08/06</td><td>$137,500</td></tr><tr><td>Rhona Davidson</td><td>Integration Specialist</td><td>Tokyo</td><td>55</td><td>2010/10/14</td><td>$327,900</td></tr><tr><td>Colleen Hurst</td><td>Javascript Developer</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>39</td><td>2009/09/15</td><td>$205,500</td></tr><tr><td>Sonya Frost</td><td>Software Engineer</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>23</td><td>2008/12/13</td><td>$103,600</td></tr><tr><td>Jena Gaines</td><td>Office Manager</td><td>London</td><td>30</td><td>2008/12/19</td><td>$90,560</td></tr><tr><td>Quinn Flynn</td><td>Support Lead</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>22</td><td>2013/03/03</td><td>$342,000</td></tr><tr><td>Charde Marshall</td><td>Regional Director</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>36</td><td>2008/10/16</td><td>$470,600</td></tr><tr><td>Haley Kennedy</td><td>Senior Marketing Designer</td><td>London</td><td>43</td><td>2012/12/18</td><td>$313,500</td></tr><tr><td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td><td>Regional Director</td><td>London</td><td>19</td><td>2010/03/17</td><td>$385,750</td></tr><tr><td>Michael Silva</td><td>Marketing Designer</td><td>London</td><td>66</td><td>2012/11/27</td><td>$198,500</td></tr><tr><td>Paul Byrd</td><td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td><td>New York</td><td>64</td><td>2010/06/09</td><td>$725,000</td></tr><tr><td>Gloria Little</td><td>Systems Administrator</td><td>New York</td><td>59</td><td>2009/04/10</td><td>$237,500</td></tr><tr><td>Bradley Greer</td><td>Software Engineer</td><td>London</td><td>41</td><td>2012/10/13</td><td>$132,000</td></tr></tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Excel has a flag that forces it to recalculate all formulas when the document is loaded, you should try that.

Comment: @TomášZato is this a solution that I can implement/prevent programatically as opposed to changing settings in Excel? If so, can you provide docs I can review?

Comment: I don't know how to do it using the libraries you're using. I just know it exists because I had to use it in the past in another programming language. But yeah, it's done programmatically and the library must support that feature.